# Generating different combinations of random numbers

Tags: ruby

While trying to experiment with Ruby and see what it can do, I put together this program to generate fake lottery numbers.

I am trying to generate all the combinations possible but it doesn't seem to work, can you see where I am going wrong?

```
lotto = [rand(1...50), rand(1...50), rand(1...50), rand(1...50), rand(1...50),  rand(1...50)].uniq

lotto_results = lotto.combination(6).cycle.to_a

puts "----START----"

count = 0

lotto_results.each do |x|
count += 1
puts "Comination #{count}: #{x}"
   puts "-------------"
  end

puts "----FINISH----"
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are you getting error messages? Incorrect (unexpected) output?

Comment: no, he's not winning the lottery!

Comment: When it cycles through it just returns the same digits thats are generated in the first call from the array => lotto instead of regenerating them each time.

Comment: Suppose `lotto = [rand(1...5), rand(1...5), rand(1...5)]`.  I get  `lotto #=> [2, 3, 2]`, so `lotto.combination(2).to_a` is the same as `[2, 3, 2].combination(2).to_a #=>[[2, 3], [2, 2], [3, 2]]`.  See the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print all possible combinations, just do the follow:

```
(1..50).to_a.combination(6).each_with_index do |c, idx| 
  puts "combination #{idx}: #{c}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
lotto = (1..50).to_a.shuffle[0..5]
```

**Addendum**

As Marc-André Lafortune points out,

```
(1..50).to_a.sample(6)
```

is much better.

Comment: How could I use this to stop when all combinations have been outputted?

Comment: This is not quite right b/c a resulting 'loto' number will have at most one of any given number.

Comment: @Alex.Bullard That's what shuffling accomplishes. The numbers 1-50 are put in a randomized order, and you take the first 6 of them.  That pretty much guarantees the uniqueness.

Comment: But this will never result in the valid loto number `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`

Comment: @Alex.Bullard That's not a valid lotto number.

Comment: @Alex.Bullard That's correct - where I live they draw actual balls, without replacement.  Hence, where I live that would not be a valid lotto number.

Comment: Ah haha. I've never played the loto, but Phillip's original solution sure made it look like it should be. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: As @iamnotmaynard pointed out, there are 15,890,700 combinations. Do you really want to output all of them?

Comment: I would bet that OP simply was not aware of how many [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) there would be. It's still a good programming exercise; just don't actually print them all out.

Answer (score 0):

```
lotto = (1..50).to_a[0..50].combination(5)

count = 0

lotto.each do |x|
count += 1
puts "Combination #{count}: #{x}"
end
```